# Is there a way to use iOS 8 Action App Extension without presenting an interface?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios8, ios-app-extension

My App's extension doesn't really require an interface to perform its function. So is there any way I can use the action extension without presenting an interface? I tried simply making the view transparent but that didn't work (it just left a gray background).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. When you create a new action extension it asks you whether or not it presents a user interface. Say "No user interface."

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even notice that was an option.

Comment: I don't think you really need a tutorial to select a menu item and then pick an option in a combo box.